# Android, no AppCompat, full screen - the most correct style?

Tags: java, android, android-fullscreen

Android app, strictly level 21 onwards only. ***Not*** using AppCompat.

Full-screen app with absolutely no bars.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.client.client">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".Main"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Am confused between:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

versus...

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```

What is the best and most modern choice?

I don't understand the complete history of the difference between those and similar values in Android :/

Again, ***not*** using AppCompat, if that matters.

Here's a screenshot of how I want the app to look on all devices:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the best and most modern choice?

With a `minSdkVersion` of 21+, you can use themes based off of `Theme.Material`, such as `Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen`.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks.  Advisable to omit the `.Light` and go with `Theme.Material.NoActionBar.Fullscreen` ?

Comment: @JoeBlow: `Light` says "light background, dark text". Skipping `Light` says "dark background, light text". Go with whatever fits your needs better.

Comment: sorry to randomly extend the QA a decade later  :)  Now that I'm on `tools:targetApi="31"` are there any new gotchyas or suggestions?  Thanks!  (Sent bounty BTW.)

Comment: @Fattie: I know that your question says "no AppCompat", but that was six years ago, and nowadays AppCompat is tough to avoid, at least for projects not using Jetpack Compose. If you are using AppCompat (e.g., extending from `AppCompatActivity`), you need an AppCompat theme or something compatible with it. But, if you are using Compose UI or are otherwise avoiding AppCompat, AFAIK using `Theme.Material`-based themes with a `minSdkVersion` of 21 or higher is still fine.

Comment: Ah, I seem to have entered a world of `.MaterialComponents` rather than `.Material` - will probe further!  TY!  :)

Comment: @Fattie: You're using Material Components for Android. You will need a `.MaterialComponents` theme for that (which is compatible with AppCompat).

Comment: You know, it would seem that this sort of thing https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive#java is the way to do it these days?  I'm giving it a go ...

Answer (score 0):

### An answer for 2022:

I have found that the only way I can do it these days is:

```
// completely fullscreen:
protected void utterlyFullScreen() {

    // go top the physical top (ie under the statusBars):
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(getWindow(), false);

    WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController =
      ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(getWindow().getDecorView());
    if (windowInsetsController == null) { return; }

    // hide the bars:
    windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars());
    // statusBars top one. navigationBars bottom one. systemBars both.

    // handle reveal:
    windowInsetsController.setSystemBarsBehavior(
      WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);

    // also:
    // windowInsetsController.setAppearanceLightNavigationBars(true);
    // or, do that in theme
}
```

I call that in every activity onCreate, after super, but before setting the view.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    utterlyFullScreen();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

I am minSdk 24 as of writing.